# How to install nokogiri gem on rhel5?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I want to install gitlab an therefore I need to install some gems.
Thereby I get the following error:

```
Installing nokogiri (1.5.9)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in -lexslt... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... no
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling xml_processing_instruction.c
In file included from ./xml_processing_instruction.h:4,
                 from xml_processing_instruction.c:1:
./nokogiri.h:13:1: warning: "_GNU_SOURCE" redefined
<command-line>: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from ./nokogiri.h:103,
                 from ./xml_processing_instruction.h:4,
                 from xml_processing_instruction.c:1:
./xml_sax_parser.h: In function ânokogiriSAXTuple* nokogiri_sax_tuple_new(xmlParserCtxt*, VALUE)â:
./xml_sax_parser.h:29: error: invalid conversion from âvoid*â to ânokogiriSAXTuple*â
xml_processing_instruction.c: At global scope:
xml_processing_instruction.c:10: error: expected unqualified-id before ânewâ
make: *** [xml_processing_instruction.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.5.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

About my System:
**RHEL 5.3,
GCC44,
G++44,
Python26,
ruby 1.9.3p0,
ruby-devel 1.9.1**

I have already checked each installation guide for nokogiri, but the error does not disappear:

e.g.

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/lib 
                             --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/include/libxml2 
                             --with-xslt-lib=/usr/local/lib 
                             --with-xslt-include=/usr/local/include
```

Also the necessary dependencies I have installed: libxml, libxml2-devel, libxml2, libxslt, libxslt-devel...

Has anybody an idea, how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe try a different version of Nokogiri?

Comment: That doesn't fix my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I have fixed the problem as follows:

```
1. libxml2 updated to libxml2-2.7.8
2. libxslt updated to libxslt-1.1.20
3. Again followed this installation guide: 
http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html
```

..and here the source of the concerning packages: http://rpm.eprints.org/RHEL/5/i386/